# Integer solutions of $a^3+2a+1=2^b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math

What are the solutions in integers of $a^3+2a+1=2^b$?

[Source: Serbian competition problem]

Comment: Related link: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=152991&

Comment: We can discount any negative solutions, the LHS will be a negative integer and the RHS will be a positive rational.

Comment: Other than $b=2$, there is no other with $2<b<1000$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equation $x^3+2x+1=2^n$ in positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662884/equation-x32x1-2n-in-positive-integers)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to start with a(a+2)=2<sup>b</sup>-1

1. We also notice that when a is odd, a<sup>2</sup>+2 is odd. likewise if a is even, a<sup>2</sup>+2 is even 
    i.) From here, we can generalize that since 2<sup>b</sup>-1 is odd for all integers a and b > 0, then *a* must always be *odd*

   ii.) We notice that the last digit of 2<sup>b</sup>-1 ossiclates between the numbers 1,3,7,5

   iii.)From ii.) the remaining values of the last digit of a can be reduced to 3, 5 and 7           
   (i.e. b mod 4= 0 or 2  ; b is a multiple of 2)

Combining all the conditions, we can form the diophantine equation: a(a<sup>2</sup>+2)=(2<sup>b</sup>+1)(2<sup>b</sup>-1)

Comment: As far as I can see, $2^b-1$ and $2^b+1$ are *always* consecutive odd numbers.

Comment: You can say it in a more simple way: $a^3 + 2a \equiv 0\pmod 3$, $2^b\equiv (-1)^b\pmod 3$; therefore $1\equiv (-1)^b \pmod 3$, and $b=2b_1$.