# Equation $x^3+2x+1=2^n$ in positive integers

Tags: diophantine-equations

Determine all pairs of positive integers $(x,n)$ which satisfy the condition
$$x^3+2x+1=2^n.$$

**My work so far:**

No solution exists for $n=1$. For $n=2$ we get $x=1$.

We show that no solutions exist for  $n\ge3$. Suppose that $n \ge 3$. Obviously, $x$ is odd. Then $x^2+2\equiv 3  \pmod 8$.  As with the original equation $x(x^2+2)\equiv -1 \pmod 8$, then $x\equiv 5\pmod 8$.

*I can not get a contradiction.*

Comment: No solution exists for $n=1$. For $n=2$ we get $x=1$.

Comment: If you've solved the problem yourself, consider posting an answer, both for future reference for those with similar problems, as well as preventing it from being stuck in the "unanswered" tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $n \ge 3$.

Note that $x \equiv 5 \pmod 8$.

Since $x^3+2x+1 \equiv 3x+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ by Fermat's little theorem,  $2^{n}$ divided by $3$ has a remainder of $1$. This implies that $n$ is a even number. Let $n=2k$.

By adding $2$ to each side, the equation can be factorized so that $$(x+1)(x^2-x+3)=2^{2k}+2.$$

Since $x^2-x+3 \equiv 23 \equiv 7 \pmod 8$, there exists a prime number $p$ where $p \equiv 5, 7\pmod8$ such that $p$ divides $x^2-x+3$. (If there is no such $p$, then $x^2-x+3 \equiv 3^{k} \pmod 8$. But $3^{k} \not \equiv 7 \pmod 8$). Since $x^2-x+3$ is a factor of $2^{2k}+2$, $p$ divides $2^{2k}+2$.

That means $(2^{k})^2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$. But $-2$ is a [non-quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Law_of_quadratic_reciprocity) of $p$ since $p \not\equiv 1,3\pmod 8$. A contradiction.

Comment: Can anyone verify if my answer is correct?

Comment: Why is $n$ an even number?

Comment: Because $x^3+2x+1 \equiv 3x+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ form Fermat's Little Theorem. This implies that $(-1)^k \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: You mean $-2$.. Note that $p$ divides $x^2-x+3$, which in turn divides $2^{2k}+2$. THis implies that $2^{2k}+2$ is divisible by $p$.